# accidently downloaded MongoDB Enterprise Server. Do I have to pay now and can i cancel it

Tags: mongodb

Question is above. I read that you have to pay for this service and now I want to cancel it. Is that possible? Or am I wrong and it is actually for free? I also tried deleting it but I keep getting the message that I can't install multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a MongoDB customer, your use of MongoDB Enterprise Server is governed by the [customer agreement](https://www.mongodb.com/customer-agreement/december-2020) that is presented during the download process (e.g. [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/enterprise/releases)). This agreement says:

> (b) Free Evaluation and Development. MongoDB grants you a royalty-free, nontransferable and nonexclusive license to use and reproduce the Software in your internal environment for evaluation and development purposes. You will not use the Software for any other purpose, including testing, quality assurance or production purposes without purchasing an Enterprise Advanced Subscription. We provide the free evaluation and development license of our Software on an “AS-IS” basis without any warranty.

You may use the product indefinitely as long as you are using it for "evaluation and development purposes".

You can also uninstall the enterprise server at any time and install the community one.